# Compiler Error in DEV-C++

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gcc-warning, dev-c++

I compiled the following code which is declared with `#include <strsafe.h>` in my C code and I am getting the following compiler errors in DEV-C++. I guess there should be some option in compiler to solve this. Can somebody help to solve this.

The below is my sample code which is taken from MSDN site :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw); 
}

void main()
{
    // Generate an error

    if(!GetProcessId(NULL))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetProcessId"));
}
```

A sample of errors from the huge set of errors.

```
154 26  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar@hubino\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h   
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'char'
155 26  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
156 1   C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__nullterminated'
156 33  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
157 26  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
158 26  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
164 38  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
165 38  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
166 38  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
173 10  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name 'STRSAFE_PCNZCH'
174 10  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__in_range'
175 15  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__deref_out_range'
179 10  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name 'STRSAFE_PCNZWCH'
180 10  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__in_range'
181 15  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__deref_out_range'
193 5   C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__deref_in_opt_out'
194 17  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__deref_out_range'
200 5   C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__deref_in_opt_out'
201 17  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name '__deref_out_range'
207 30  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name 'STRSAFE_PCNZCH'
213 30  C:\Documents and Settings\mkumar\Desktop\DEVC\TEST-install-Driver-Difx\TO-DO\strsafe.h  
[Error] unknown type name 'STRSAFE_LPCSTR'
continues.......
```

A part of strsafe.h file from where I am getting the above errors :

```
//
// These typedefs are used in places where the string is guaranteed to
// be null terminated.
//
typedef __nullterminated char* STRSAFE_LPSTR;
typedef __nullterminated const char* STRSAFE_LPCSTR;
typedef __nullterminated wchar_t* STRSAFE_LPWSTR;
typedef __nullterminated const wchar_t* STRSAFE_LPCWSTR;
typedef __nullterminated const wchar_t UNALIGNED* STRSAFE_LPCUWSTR;

//
// These typedefs are used in places where the string is NOT guaranteed to
// be null terminated.
//
typedef __possibly_notnullterminated const char* STRSAFE_PCNZCH;
typedef __possibly_notnullterminated const wchar_t* STRSAFE_PCNZWCH;
typedef __possibly_notnullterminated const wchar_t UNALIGNED* STRSAFE_PCUNZWCH;


// prototypes for the worker functions

STRSAFEWORKERAPI
StringLengthWorkerA(
    __in STRSAFE_PCNZCH psz,
    __in __in_range(<=, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH) size_t cchMax,
    __out_opt __deref_out_range(<, cchMax) size_t* pcchLength);

STRSAFEWORKERAPI
StringLengthWorkerW(
    __in STRSAFE_PCNZWCH psz,
    __in __in_range(<=, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH) size_t cchMax,
    __out_opt __deref_out_range(<, cchMax) size_t* pcchLength);

#ifdef ALIGNMENT_MACHINE
STRSAFEWORKERAPI
UnalignedStringLengthWorkerW(
    __in STRSAFE_PCUNZWCH psz,
    __in __in_range(<=, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH) size_t cchMax,
    __out_opt __deref_out_range(<, cchMax) size_t* pcchLength);
#endif  // ALIGNMENT_MACHINE

STRSAFEWORKERAPI
StringExValidateSrcA(
    __deref_in_opt_out STRSAFE_LPCSTR* ppszSrc,
    __inout_opt __deref_out_range(<, cchMax) size_t* pcchToRead,
    __in const size_t cchMax,
    __in DWORD dwFlags);
```

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the offending code as well.

Comment: Consider writing a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/), and edit your question to include the code.

Comment: The only error is with strsafe.h.

Comment: @user1317084 did you forgot to post `strsafe.h`? Without it you probably won't get any answer.

Comment: Thanks,I have posted a part of the strsafe.h from where the error starts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__nullterminated, __out_opt, __in, __in_opt and other such words are Microsoft-specific keywords. When you use gcc you can just define them to be empty macros like

```
#define __in
#define __deref_out_range(A,B)
... and so on
```

Insert these defines before the includes.

Or as the comments suggest avoid using the `<strsafe.h>`

EDIT:

MinGW (x64 build from http://equation.com) compiles this code above quietly (even with `strsafe.h`) with just a simple command:

```
gcc -c Test.cpp -o Test.exe -lstdc++
```

Comment: You mean I want define all those macros? And no other way to avoid this,like using some compiler options? And sorry for asking this no where in comments they said to avoid using strsafe.h .. Please suggest..

Comment: I only propose the solution which worked for me (I used DirectX 11 headers with MinGW/GCC - there were plenty of __in_opt and stuff). By the way, I checked your code with MinGW and it compiles quietly.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. May I know command used for compilation if possible please. Because my devcon internally calls Mingw only.

Comment: Added to my answer, by I don't really think this command would help you much. There's just something strange with your header setup. Looks like your MinGW refers to VC++ headers somehow (from Windows SDK maybe ?)

Comment: yes I am refering to the SDK strsafe.h .. But any tips to solve this? Because I dont have strsafe.h file anywhere in my computer, than SDK.

Comment: I've mentioned the solution: GCC _must_ use its own "adapted" version of WinSDK. The one for MinGW can be downloaded from http://equation.com  (it's a complete toolchain with Boost and some other libs).  Download links are at the bottom: http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran