# What does this typedef mean involving LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, windows, char, sal, lpwstr

I am trying to find a substitute for LPWSTR for porting a project to gcc.

```
typedef __nullterminated WCHAR *NWPSTR, *LPWSTR, *PWSTR;
```

What is null terminated ? so would it be safe if I did something like this:

```
typedef WCHAR   *LPWSTR
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648246/compiler-error-in-dev-c . The accepted answer talks about those symbols a bit.

Comment: `__nullterminated` looks like a compiler-specific extension. In any case, `LPWSTR` is simply a pointer to a wide character (with the intent being that that character is the first in an array of characters, ending with a null character, thus forming a string). Your typedef is fine (though it's missing the semicolon).

Comment: so `typedef WCHAR   *LPWSTR ` can be used as a substitue ?

Comment: @Misty: Yes. You read faster than I could ninja-edit my comment :-) If you're using GCC on Windows, though, there should already be a header somewhere that defines these types. (e.g. MinGW has its own version of `windows.h`.)

Comment: I am using cygwin-gcc

Comment: It is just a do-nothing macro, not a keyword, code analyzers can use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> typedef __nullterminated WCHAR *NWPSTR, *LPWSTR, *PWSTR;

The **`__nullterminated`** part is a *SAL annotation*. SAL is a Microsoft specific technology to annotate function parameters, return values, function behaviors, etc. to help finding bugs and reduce C/C++ code defects using the Visual Studio Code Analysis tool. You can read about SAL here on MSDN:

> [**Using SAL Annotations to Reduce C/C++ Code Defects**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx)

**`WCHAR`** is defined in the Windows Platform SDK headers basically as a typedef for `wchar_t`, which is a **16-bit** character type in the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler. This is used as a *"character unit"* for the **Unicode UTF-16** encoding, which is the default *de facto* Unicode encoding of Windows APIs.
Note that other compilers like GNU GCC on Linux consider `wchar_t` to be a *32-bit* character unit (*not* 16-bit), so you have to pay attention here for the portability of your code.

(Note: Modern versions of Windows support Unicode UTF-16 with the so called *surrogate pairs*, so you can have a *couple* of adjacent `WCHAR`s defining a surrogate pair.)

**`NWPSTR`**, **`LPWSTR`** and **`PWSTR`** are all synonyms, defined as *pointers* to `WCHAR`, i.e. considering also the `__nullterminated` SAL annotation, they are pointers to *"raw"* **C-style NUL-terminated Unicode UTF-16 strings**.

Basically, this is the Windows Win32 Unicode equivalent of the classical C's `char*`.

I've been programming Windows in C++ for several years, and I've never met this `NWPSTR` to be honest :)

The name `PWSTR` is built using the following elements:

- `P`: pointer
- `W`: *"wide"*, i.e. `WCHAR`/`wchar_t`-based, i.e. Unicode UTF-16
- `STR`: string

So, `PWSTR` means a pointer to a `WCHAR`/`wchar_t` string, i.e. a Unicode UTF-16 string, as already stated above.

`LPWSTR` is just an old name for the same thing; the initial `L` means *"long"*, and that dates back to a time when there were *"long pointers"* which could access memory farther than "short" or "near" pointers :) Those days are no more.

And, if you put a **`C`** in those names, you have typedefs for the read-only **`const`** counterparts, e.g.: **`PCWSTR`** or **`LPCWSTR`** are basically **`const wchar_t*`** NUL-terminated Unicode UTF-16 strings.

You will find `PCWSTR` and the older equivalent `LPCWSTR` used *a lot* in Windows header files and Windows API documentation to represent **Unicode UTF-16** *"input"* (i.e. `const`) **C-style NUL-terminated strings**.